# TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here is my code:

```py
html = open("meetup.html", "r") 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

file = open('myfile.txt', 'w')
for elem in soup.find_all(attrs={"type": "application/ld+json"}):
    file.write(elem)
   
file.close()
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not Tag
```

I get that I need to convert the tag object to a string, but I don't know how to do this. Trying

```py
file.write(elem.text)
```

return an empty file. I don't know where that is instructed in [Beautiful Soup Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all).

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: Now the summary is mesleading.  Also, nobody knows what's in your HTML file.

Comment: This will find elements with a `type="application/ld+json"` attribute.  Can you show us a few examples of such elements from your html file?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<script type="application/ld+json">
["This is an example"]
</script>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

with open("output_file.txt", "w") as f_out:
    for elem in soup.find_all(attrs={"type": "application/ld+json"}):
        print(elem.text, file=f_out)
```

Then the file `output_file.txt` will contain:

```
["This is an example"]
```

Comment: hmm, looks like something has happened with my interpreter. The output file is still empty with your example script

Comment: @Ooker try to use different parser, for example ´html5lib´

Comment: it works. Why can't `html.parser` work for this?

Comment: @Ooker Every parser has some limitations... `html.parser` is sufficient in most cases and is fast, `html5lib` is slow but parser HTML as close as the browsers.

Comment: I see. But why can it work on your machine but not mine?

Answer (score 0):

As Andrej Kesely points out, it's because of the parser. Using:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
```

works